# The term 'RSpec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, error

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test ruby file using rspec. But I'm getting error and It says

```
rspec : The term 'rspec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ rspec test2.rb
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (rspec:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axHV5.png)

How can I fix this.
Here I attached my all 3 ruby files also
user.rb

```
require_relative 'main'

print 'Input array: '
solution = Solution.new(gets.split.map(&:to_f))

if solution.posled?
  puts "Yes, posled: #{solution.arr_new}"
else
  puts 'No'
end
```

main.rb

```
# This class is responsible for checking is the elements before first negative sorted from min to max.
class Solution
  attr_accessor :arr_new, :arr

  def initialize(arr)
    @arr = arr
    @arr_new = []
    @was_negative = false
    @arr.each_with_index do |value, _index|
      if value.negative?
        @was_negative = true
        break
      else
        @arr_new.push(value)
      end
    end
  end

  def posled?(arr_new = @arr_new)
    if arr_new.any? && @was_negative
      arr_new == arr_new.sort
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

test2.rb

```
require_relative 'main2'

RSpec.describe Solution do
  describe '#Solution' do
    it 'should return true' do
      expect(Solution.posled?([1, 2, 3])).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'should return true if contains posled before negative el' do
      uncorrect = [1, 2, 3, -1]
      Random.rand(10).times { uncorrect.push(Random.rand(-10..9)) }
      expect(Solution.posled?(uncorrect)).to eq(true)
    end

    it 'should return false if there is no posled before first neg el' do
      uncorrect = [1, 3, 2, -1]
      Random.rand(10).times { uncorrect.push(Random.rand(-10..9)) }
      expect(Solution.posled?(uncorrect)).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'should return false if first el negative' do
      uncorrect = [-1, 1, 2, 3]
      Random.rand(10).times { uncorrect.push(Random.rand(-10..9)) }
      expect(Solution.posled?(uncorrect)).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'should return false if there is no negative elements' do
      uncorrect = [1, 2, 3]
      Random.rand(10).times { uncorrect.push(Random.rand(-10..9)) }
      expect(Solution.posled?(uncorrect)).to eq(false)
    end
  end
end
```

I tried ruby test file and looking for get errors and corrections. But when I run rspec I'm getting an error. How can I fix this

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to rub `rspec` from Powershell? Are you certain you have installed `rspec` correctly ?

Comment: yeah, rspec is not (properly) installed and can't be executed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the ruby files, according to your first output the command is not found.

There might be different reasons for this. Can you run `ruby -version` either in cmd or powershell? If it works, than you should check if rspec is installed within your ruby instance. Run `gem list rspec` the output should be like this:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rspec (3.12.0)
rspec-core (3.12.0)
rspec-expectations (3.12.0)
rspec-mocks (3.12.0)
rspec-support (3.12.0)
```

If it is found try reinstalling it with `gem uninstall rspec` and than `gem install rspec`.

In case neither `ruby` nor `rspec` work, you should check you PATH variable with `echo %PATH%` in cmd or `$Env:Path` in Powershell. There should be a record pointing to ruby bin folder.

The other thing to keep in mind is you may have multiple ruby versions installed. [RubyInstaller website](https://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/uru.html) suggests using `uru`. If you've installed ruby with **uru**, you first need to activate your ruby instance. Either in Powershell or cmd run `uru ls` to see all the versions installed. In my case:

```
187p374     : ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i386-mingw32]
233p222     : ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
253p105     : ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x64-mingw32]
268p205     : ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [x64-mingw32]
274p191     : ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x64-mingw32]
310p0       : ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [i386-mingw32]
jruby       : jruby 9.2.19.0 (2.5.8) 2021-06-15 55810c552b Java HotSpot(TM) 64...
main        : ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x64-mingw32]
```

You have to select one of the listed versions, e.g. `uru main`, than all the ruby commands and installed gems should work for the opened Powershell or cmd session, **path** output will also feature the selected version.

In case you have some other software to manage multiple ruby versions please refer to its documentation.